# Fetch headers from one table and data from another

Tags: php, mysql

Am not sure how to query two tables and echo the results on a web page. I have two tables, commodities table has commodity types eg cereals, pulses, vegetables, the other table has types of commodities ie, maize, sorghum rows have an ID pointing to commodities table, cereals unique id. I want to fetch  a multi-dimension array of all commodities and the produce without repeating commodities.

my commodities table has two columns uniq_id and commodity_name
produce table has two columns produce_name commodity_id.

I would like to fetch all commodities are their produce and display in a list in such a manner:

```
<ol>
    <li> commodity name 
       <ol>
           <li> produce name </li>
           <li> produce name </li>
       </ol>
    </li>
    <li> commodity name 
       <ol>
           <li> produce name </li>
           <li> produce name </li>
       </ol>
    </li>

</ol>
```

kindly assist.

Comment: What you have tried so far??

Comment: SELECT commodities.commodity_name
                FROM commodities WHERE commodities.uniq_id IN
    (SELECT produce.* FROM produce WHERE commodities.uniq_id = produce.commodity_id)

Comment: that brings this error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Comment: I had tried left join earlier, gives me results but there was repetition of commodity names, which is what Ive been trying to avoid

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT commodities.commodity_name FROM commodities WHERE commodities.uniq_id IN (SELECT produce.commodity_id  FROM produce WHERE commodities.uniq_id = produce.commodity_id)
```

Comment: still not working. var_dump($results) gives me this object(mysqli_result)#15 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: pasted the query as you sent it. $sql = "SELECT commodities.commodity_name 
  FROM commodities 
  WHERE commodities.uniq_id 
  IN (SELECT produce.commodity_id  FROM produce WHERE commodities.uniq_id = produce.commodity_id)";

Comment: then i var_dump the result of that query. Seems no data is fetched, Very weird.

Comment: is query giving any results if you directly paste in PHPMYAdmin??